# Calculate $\int_0^{5p} f(x) dx$ for period $p$.

Tags: calculus

Let the $p$ be a period of the $f(x)
$

$f(x) = |\sin x  + \cos x|$

Find the $S = \int_0 ^{5p } f(x) dx$

---

Here is my attempt. The answer is $10 \sqrt2:$
[image]

But whenever I did the answer dosen't come at all.

Is the answer not correct, isn't it?

Comment: $\cos (x + \pi) \neq \cos(x) $

Comment: Hmm I will try it again

Comment: If $f$ is a periodic function with period $p$, then $\int_y^{y+mp} f(z)dz$ will be independent of choice of $y$ for any integer $m$, you can compute your integral over a interval more convenient, e.g. $(-\frac{\pi}{4},-\frac{\pi}{4}+5\pi)$.

Comment: Clearly $S=5\int_0^pf(x)\,dx$. And, by periodicity $\int_0^\pi f=\int_{-\pi/4}^{3\pi/4}f$, an interval where you can ignore the absolute values.

Comment: @Riquelme But $|\cos(x+\pi)|=|\cos x|$.

Comment: Unrelated. 9√2 + 1 is not 10√2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be simpler to just write
$$\begin{align}
S
&=\int_0^{5\pi}|\sqrt{2}\sin{(x+\pi/4)}|\mathrm{d}x\\
&=5\int_0^{\pi}|\sqrt{2}\sin{(x+\pi/4)}|\mathrm{d}x\\
&=5\left(\int_0^{3\pi/4}\sqrt{2}\sin{(x+\pi/4)}\mathrm{d}x-\int_{3\pi/4}^{\pi}\sqrt{2}\sin{(x+\pi/4)}\mathrm{d}x\right)\\
&=\cdots\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Terrific solution!! Thank you.